# Set theory functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets $A,B$, explicitly write the set of all functions from A to B $\{f | f : A \mapsto B\}$.

1. $A=\{1,2\}$ , $B=\{1,2,3\}$
2. $A=\{1,2,3\}$ , $B=\{1,2\}$

I'm not sure if I'm right, but I think I got 1:
$${F =} {\left\{\raise{3.25ex}{\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\},\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle\},\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle\},\\ \{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\},\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle\},\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle\},\\\{\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\},\{\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle\},\{\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle\}}\right\}}$$

Am I doing it right? If the answer is yes then I think 2 is way longer than 1.

Comment: Looks correct to me! Note that we always have $|B|^{|A|}$ number of functions from $A$ to $B$. I guess the only important thing here is to make sure to write the functions in such a way that you don't forget one (which you perfectly did for part 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing okay; the first set should contain $3^2$ sets of $2$ pairs each, and those are what they are.

The next set should likewise contain $2^3$ sets of $3$ pairs each.   Use the same procedure to find them all. $$\Big\{\big\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle\big\},\ldots,\big\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 3,2\rangle\big\}\Big\} $$

Comment: Thanks! One more question.. Let $A=\emptyset$, will F be $\{\emptyset\}$ or just $\emptyset$?

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, then $F$ will contain $\lvert B\rvert^{\lvert\emptyset\rvert}$ sets of $\lvert\emptyset\rvert$ pairs ( $F=\{\{\}\}$ ).